# Addon nfs was not found in any repository microk8s

Tags: microk8s

I have a microk8s cluster with 3 nodes, running in multipass on Ubuntu 22.04.
All running on my old Macbookpro mid2012. (with ubuntu, 22.04 i removed Macos)

I m getting this message when i execute the command:

```
microk8s enable nfs

Addon nfs was not found in any repository
```

I installed nfs on all 3 multipass intances.

```
sudo apt install -y nfs-common
```

dns enabled
dashbord enabled
I can access the cluster from my host ubuntu.

```
kubectl get node
NAME       STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
worker01   Ready    <none>   40m   v1.24.8-2+1dda18a15eea38
master     Ready    <none>   46m   v1.24.8-2+1dda18a15eea38
worker02   Ready    <none>   42m   v1.24.8-2+1dda18a15eea38
```

following pods are running

```
kubectl get po -A
NAMESPACE     NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE
kube-system   calico-node-hv6sd                            1/1     Running   0             84m
kube-system   calico-node-wbm9h                            1/1     Running   0             82m
kube-system   coredns-66bcf65bb8-s7xjx                     1/1     Running   0             40m
kube-system   calico-node-cwfzt                            1/1     Running   1 (60m ago)   84m
kube-system   calico-kube-controllers-655d5f4c66-d7q8q     1/1     Running   0             87m
ingress       nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-2fgwk      1/1     Running   0             38m
kube-system   metrics-server-5f8f64cb86-p4tcn              1/1     Running   0             36m
kube-system   dashboard-metrics-scraper-6b6f796c8d-vp4j5   1/1     Running   0             35m
ingress       nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-7vjgh      1/1     Running   0             38m
ingress       nginx-ingress-microk8s-controller-qzwsj      1/1     Running   0             38m
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard-765646474b-s89wj        1/1     Running   0             35m
```

Execute also

```
microk8s enable community
```

The message is always the same.
Addon nfs was not found in any repository

```
ubuntu@master:~$ microk8s enable community
Infer repository core for addon community
Addon core/community is already enabled
ubuntu@master:~$ microk8s enable nfs
Addon nfs was not found in any repository
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nfs addon is quite new. I had the same problem with microk8s 1.24.0, it wasn't part of the list. I updated my nodes to 1.26.0, then had to disable and re-enable the community addon, and it showed up in the list.

Comment: Yes i did same , downgrading from 1.25 to 1.24 didnt help. With 1.26 it was installed immediatly after enabled community and nfs then.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I think there is no `nfs` modules on `microk8s`. On my Ubuntu 22.04.1 Server, the available modules are listed below:

```bash
$ microk8s status
microk8s is running
high-availability: no
  datastore master nodes: 127.0.0.1:19001
  datastore standby nodes: none
addons:
  enabled:
    dashboard            # (core) The Kubernetes dashboard
    dns                  # (core) CoreDNS
    ha-cluster           # (core) Configure high availability on the current node
    helm                 # (core) Helm - the package manager for Kubernetes
    helm3                # (core) Helm 3 - the package manager for Kubernetes
    ingress              # (core) Ingress controller for external access
    metrics-server       # (core) K8s Metrics Server for API access to service metrics
    rbac                 # (core) Role-Based Access Control for authorisation
  disabled:
    cert-manager         # (core) Cloud native certificate management
    community            # (core) The community addons repository
    gpu                  # (core) Automatic enablement of Nvidia CUDA
    host-access          # (core) Allow Pods connecting to Host services smoothly
    hostpath-storage     # (core) Storage class; allocates storage from host directory
    kube-ovn             # (core) An advanced network fabric for Kubernetes
    mayastor             # (core) OpenEBS MayaStor
    metallb              # (core) Loadbalancer for your Kubernetes cluster
    observability        # (core) A lightweight observability stack for logs, traces and metrics
    prometheus           # (core) Prometheus operator for monitoring and logging
    registry             # (core) Private image registry exposed on localhost:32000
    storage              # (core) Alias to hostpath-storage add-on, deprecated
```

For the NFS implementation, you need to have NFS server configured and create storage driver on the cluster.

**Requirements**

You should already have a NFS server outside the clusters, you can use the hosts or spawn another VM and configure NFS server with below configuration:

```bash
# Assuming you use Ubuntu VM
# Install the NFS Kernel
sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server

# Create a directory to be used for NFS
sudo mkdir -p /srv/nfs
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /srv/nfs
sudo chmod 0777 /srv/nfs
```

Then edit the `/etc/exports` file. Make sure that the IP addresses of all your MicroK8s nodes are able to mount this share. For example, to allow all IP addresses in the `10.0.0.0/24` subnet:

```bash
sudo mv /etc/exports /etc/exports.bak
echo '/srv/nfs 10.0.0.0/24(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)' | sudo tee /etc/exports
```

Finally, restart the NFS server:

```bash
sudo systemctl restart nfs-kernel-server
```

Please adjust with your configuration.

**Installation method on clusters:**

1. Install the CSI driver for NFS

We will use the [upstream NFS CSI driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs). First, we will deploy the NFS provisioner using the official Helm chart.

Enable the Helm3 addon (if not already enabled) and add the repository for the NFS CSI driver:

```bash
microk8s enable helm3
microk8s helm3 repo add csi-driver-nfs https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-csi/csi-driver-nfs/master/charts
microk8s helm3 repo update
```

Then, install the Helm chart under the `kube-system` namespace with:

```bash
microk8s helm3 install csi-driver-nfs csi-driver-nfs/csi-driver-nfs \
    --namespace kube-system \
    --set kubeletDir=/var/snap/microk8s/common/var/lib/kubelet
```

After deploying the Helm chart, wait for the CSI controller and node pods to come up using the following `kubectl` command …

```bash
microk8s kubectl wait pod --selector app.kubernetes.io/name=csi-driver-nfs --for condition=ready --namespace kube-system
```

… which, once successful, will produce output similar to:

```bash
pod/csi-nfs-controller-7bd5678cbc-nc6l2 condition met
pod/csi-nfs-node-lsn6n condition met
```

At this point, you should also be able to list the available CSI drivers in your Kubernetes cluster …

```bash
microk8s kubectl get csidrivers
```

… and see nfs.csi.k8s.io in the list:

```bash
NAME             ATTACHREQUIRED   PODINFOONMOUNT   STORAGECAPACITY   TOKENREQUESTS   REQUIRESREPUBLISH   MODES        AGE
nfs.csi.k8s.io   false            false            false             <unset>         false               Persistent   23h
```

2. Create a StorageClass for NFS

Next, we will need to create a Kubernetes Storage Class that uses the `nfs.csi.k8s.io` CSI driver. Assuming you have configured an NFS share `/srv/nfs` and the address of your NFS server is `10.0.0.1`, create the following file:

```bash
# sc-nfs.yaml
---
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: nfs-csi
provisioner: nfs.csi.k8s.io
parameters:
  server: 10.0.0.1
  share: /srv/nfs
reclaimPolicy: Delete
volumeBindingMode: Immediate
mountOptions:
  - hard
  - nfsvers=4.1
```

> Note: The last line of the above YAML indicates a specific version of
> NFS. This should match the version of the NFS server being used - if
> you are using an existing service please check which version it uses
> and adjust accordingly.

Then apply it on your `MicroK8s` cluster with:

```bash
microk8s kubectl apply -f - < sc-nfs.yaml
```

3. Create a new PVC

The final step is to create a new PersistentVolumeClaim using the nfs-csi storage class. This is as simple as specifying `storageClassName: nfs-csi` in the PVC definition, for example:

```bash
# pvc-nfs.yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: test-pvc
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-csi
  accessModes: [ReadWriteOnce]
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Then create the PVC with:

```bash
microk8s kubectl apply -f - < pvc-nfs.yaml
```

If everything has been configured correctly, you should be able to check the PVC…

```bash
microk8s kubectl describe pvc/test-pvc
```

… and see that a volume was provisioned successfully:

```bash
Name:          test-pvc
Namespace:     default
StorageClass:  nfs-csi
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-0d7e0c27-a6d6-4b64-9451-3209f98d6472
Labels:        <none>
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: nfs.csi.k8s.io
               volume.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: nfs.csi.k8s.io
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      5Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Used By:       <none>
Events:        <none>
```

That’s it! You can now use this PVC to run stateful workloads on your MicroK8s cluster.

You just need to re-create point 3 to create new PVC.

Comment: Thank you for your big effort. But this is not what i need. I have several live cluster running with nfs. If you take a look here https://microk8s.io/docs/addon-nfs. This is the microK8s addon for nfs. (addon comunity is also need). The error comes however. Maybe the version off microk8s doesnt support the addon. But i downgraded it already to 1.24. I installed it on my Laptop just to test something when answering some questions on the Stackexchange sites. Thank you again for your excellent tutorial of how to configure nfs. But as i said this doesnt answer my question.

Comment: Hi @Ralle, I have the same issue. I was thinking that it's was related to the fact that I cannot install `nfs-common` in a snap environment. But I'm interested to know if you have this add-on on version 1.24 of Microk8s.

Comment: Hi @Duc, i added the repo manually and i could install it.Not using it for now for time issues. As soon i can work on it i will add a working answer.

Comment: Hi again, on version 1.26 it works fine. Provvisoner , storageClass was installed automatically @Duc